# past simple for recent past

Tags: past-tense

> I received only today the records you sent nearly a year ago.
>
> It was not until November that I received the records which had been sent nearly a year earlier, in January.

Why in the second sentence past perfect seems obligatory. It is obvious that a year earlier is linked to until november and that is before november. Is it because until november draws the event **"really"** **in the past** where as received only today draws the event "**not completly in the past"**. I don't know if my question is clear enough to be understood

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the past perfect is obligatory in the second sentence, although it certainly reads better with the past perfect, rather than with "which *were* sent".

The main reason for using the past perfect is that it emphasizes that an event took place in the past **before another event in the past**.  In the first sentence, the sequence of events is like this:

April 2016: the records are sent...April 29th, 2017: you receive the records and say the sentence.

In the second sentence, the sequence of events is like this:

January: the records are sent...November: the records are received...Today: you talk about what happened in November.

The use of the past perfect is to emphasize that as of November, the records *had already been sent* almost a year earlier.

References:

- [Past Perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense/past-perfect)
- [The Past Perfect Tense](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/pastperf.htm)
- [Past Simple or Past Perfect?](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/past-simple-or-past-perfect)